# Electromagnetic waves interference

Tags: forces, electrostatics, photons, interferometry

Two charged bodies create a superposition of electrostatic fields at a point and there is no evidence of fields interference. Now, if we put two current circuits around the charged bodies then we create also magnetic fields and as a consequence two electromagnetic fields. If the electrostatic field and the magnetic field from the two positions don't interfere as waves when independently acting will their combination in the form of electromagnetic field show interference properties when combined?By interference I don't mean just only adding up or subtracting of non oscillating fields at large scale but the possibility of cancellation at small scale like in the double slit experiment where you get frindges!

Comment: But it is "field interference". The principle of superposition states that two (or more) charges create an electric field so that at any point in space, the resultant electric field is a vector sum of the electric field due to the individual charges.

Comment: There won't be electromagnetic fields in the case you describe above as electromagnetic waves do not mean the coincidence of an static electric field and a magnetic field. Electromagnetic fields (light!) are different phenomena to what you have described.

Answer (score 1):

EM waves interfere according to the mathematics of superposition. So there will be superposition and interference (constructive or destructive) of the E field and B field.

There won't be waves, because there is no time-based oscillation in the situation you described.